# $this->session->set_flashdata() and then $this->session->flashdata() doesn't work in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

Please take a look at the following code:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'This is a message.');
var_dump($this->session->flashdata('message'));
```

It returns `bool(false)`.

I hope it doesn't ***NEED*** a `redirect()` to be recallable after that, because some times I need to call it right after setting the flashdata in a view.

---

**Edit** after [venkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679342/venkat)'s comment

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'This is a message.');
$this->session->keep_flashdata('message');
var_dump($this->session->flashdata('message'));
```

No difference unfortunately.

Comment: CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared. If you wanna preserve flash data through an additional request use this one $this->session->keep_flashdata('message'); If i am wrong please let me know...........

Comment: Thank you dear @Venkat, but no difference. I updated my question.

Comment: Possibly flashdata is only retrievable upon the next server request? Also of course make sure you have session loaded correctly with encryption key etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Of course I have set those configs to use sessions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) does actually state that

> CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be
>   available for the next server request, and are then automatically
>   cleared.

as the very first thing, which obviusly means that you need to do a new server request.
A redirect, a refresh, a link or some other mean to send the user to the next request.

Why use flashdata if you are using it in the same request, anyway? You'd might as well not use flashdata or use a regular session.

Comment: Thnak you, yes, I read the document after asking my question!!! Anyway wish I could use `flashdata` because the real mean for such purposes is `flashdata`, not normal session. Another reason is that now I have to use it the more manual way because I should think about unsetting message sessions after displaying them.

Comment: Not necessarily - an option would be to [extend CI](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) with your own Session Library which allows for direct access to the flashdata after it's been set.

Comment: automatically cleared? What is the alternative that is NOT automatically cleared then ? @Repox

Comment: @gumuruh The alternative is to not use flashdata, but just use session data or cookies.

Answer (score 20):

```
// Set flash data 
$this->session->set_flashdata('message_name', 'This is my message');
// After that you need to used redirect function instead of load view such as 
redirect("admin/signup");

// Get Flash data on view 
$this->session->flashdata('message_name');
```

Answer (score 12):

To set flashdata you need to redirect controller function

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message_name', 'This is test message');

//redirect to some function
redirect("controller/function_name");

//echo in view or controller
$this->session->flashdata('message_name');
```

Answer (score 8):

Displaying a flash message after redirect in Codeigniter

In Your Controller set this

```
<?php

public function change_password(){







if($this->input->post('submit')){
$change = $this->common_register->change_password();

if($change == true){
$messge = array('message' => 'Password chnage successfully','class' => 'alert alert-success fade in');
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', $messge);
}else{
$messge = array('message' => 'Wrong password enter','class' => 'alert alert-danger fade in');
$this->session->set_flashdata('item',$messge );
}
$this->session->keep_flashdata('item',$messge);



redirect('controllername/methodname','refresh');
}

?>

In Your View File Set this
<script type="application/javascript">
/** After windod Load */
$(window).bind("load", function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}, 4000);
});
</script>

<?php

if($this->session->flashdata('item')) {
$message = $this->session->flashdata('item');
?>
<div class="<?php echo $message['class'] ?>"><?php echo $message['message']; ?>

</div>
<?php
}

?>
```

Please check below link for [Displaying a flash message after redirect in Codeigniter](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2016/06/displaying-flash-message-after-redirect.html)

Answer (score 3):

Change your config.php:

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

To:

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
```

It works for me.

Comment: but that isn't exist in my config of codeigniter 3. @Crashed

Answer (score -2):

flash message after redirect will available in controller not in view.
to show in view get in controller's action and pass it view