# codeigniter flashdata works inside false if statement

Tags: php, codeigniter

i not new to codeigniter 2
but i wasn't using flashdata before and i started to use it today
i got strange issues
i'm creating if statment

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('blocks', array('block_id' => $id));
    if($query->num_rows() < 1)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata(array('notify_type'=>'error', 'notify_msg'=>'some error msg'));
        return false;
    }           
    return $query->row();
```

the problem is ,
my model returns the query perfect
and also the flashdata triggers
i'm sure num_row is < 1 and if not i has to `return false;`
but its returns the query 
any help !!

Comment: ??Cannot understand.

Comment: sry my english isn't first lang.
in short , the model return $query->row and also flashdata works

Comment: i don't know why flashdata works here !!

Comment: flush data only works for next server request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [Session Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

**CodeIgniter supports “flashdata”, or session data that will only be available for the next request, and is then automatically cleared.
This can be very useful, especially for one-time informational, error or status messages**

See also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109522/this-session-set-flashdata-and-then-this-session-flashdata-doesnt-wor)